# Python map function doesn't use the new values but the originals

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-itertools

I'm using Python 3.4.11 on Windows 10.

I need solution to a trouble I'm suffering when trying to detect overlapped periods of time.

To get a solution I created a dataframe so it is analyzed line by line, evaluating the previous row.
The function

It is necessary to take the map results to be evaluated many times in the same calculation. For example if a person worked from:
2021-01-01 to 2024-12-31 for company A and from 2021-06-01 to 2022-05-10 in company B it is completely contained.
Then the same person worked from 2023-02-15 to 2023-09-28 in company C, so the second period is half overlapped considering the first line, and this is my problem, my code works evaluating the second period but not the third. So I need the map function to evaluate the new value of FIRST_DATE and LAST_DATE, not the originals.

I thank you all since now.

```
def eval_overlap_first_time(id1,id0,first_date_1,first_date0,last_date1,last_date0):
    if id1==id0:
        if first_date1<=last_date0:
            #TOTALLY CONTAINED
            if last_date1<=last_date0:
                resultado=first_date0
            else:
                #HALF CONTAINED
                if last_date1>=last_date0:
                    resultado=first_date0
        else:
            resultado=first_date_1
    else:
            resultado=first_date_1
    return resultado

def eval_overlap_last_time(id1,id0,first_date_1,first_date0,last_date1,last_date0):
    if id1==id0:
        if first_date_1<=last_date0:
            #TOTALLY CONTAINED
            if last_date1<=last_date0:
                resultado=last_date0
            else:
                #HALF CONTAINED
                if last_date1>=last_date0:
                    resultado=last_date1
        else:
            resultado=last_date1
    else:
            resultado=last_date1
    return resultado


c_aux['FIRST_DATE']=list(map(eval_overlap_first_time,c_aux['ID'],c_aux['ID'].shift(1).fillna('12345678'),c_aux['FIRST_DATE'],c_aux['FIRST_DATE'].shift(1).fillna(dt.date(9999,12,31)),c_aux['LAST_DATE'],c_aux['LAST_DATE'].shift(1).fillna(dt.date(9999,12,31))))
c_aux['FECHA_EGRESO']=list(map(eval_overlap_lastst_time,c_aux['ID'],c_aux['ID'].shift(1).fillna('12345678'),c_aux['FIRST_DATE'],c_aux['FIRST_DATE'].shift(1).fillna(dt.date(9999,12,31)),c_aux['LAST_DATE'],c_aux['LAST_DATE'].shift(1).fillna(dt.date(9999,12,31))))
```

Also I tried to use itertools function starmap and zip but had no good result.
I need the output of an iteration the input for the next one.

Comment: Which is it, one of the currently in support versions of Python 3, or the dead-for-years-now Python 2.7? Because one of those tags needs to get removed.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans it is Python 3.11.4 version

Comment: Remember, you're asking _everyone_ for help, so don't just tell me, tell everyone by putting that information [in your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76782340/edit).

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans it's the first time I ask something here. Thanks!

Comment: Can you make a copy of the dataframe, and assign the results to the copy? Then you can keep processing the old values from the original df.

Comment: Sorry, but this really needs a [mcve]. As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].